# Bazel hangs on java binary

Tags: java, tensorflow, centos, bazel, helios

I am trying to reinstall bazel on a the same machine after an OS upgrade. Following the same steps the same bazel version is giving problem when calling it. I assume the problem has to do with the java binary, but I have no idea how to further debug it. Do you have suggestions on how to further debug this?

After calling the bazel 0.19.1 installer the build hangs on

" Extracting Bazel installation..."

When calling strace on 'bazel help' or "bazel version" I get:

futex(0x7f93131bc9d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 8279, NULL
at the end

When calling bazel --client_debug --batch version I get:

- [bazel INFO src/main/cpp/option_processor.cc:362] Looking for the following rc files: /etc/bazel.bazelrc,/export/home/sdc/.bazelrc
- [bazel INFO src/main/cpp/blaze.cc:1549] Debug logging requested, sending all client log statements to stderr
- [bazel INFO src/main/cpp/blaze.cc:1569] Acquired the client lock, waited 0 milliseconds
- [bazel INFO src/main/cpp/blaze.cc:725] Starting Bazel in batch mode.
  [bazel INFO src/main/cpp/blaze_util_posix.cc:226] Invoking binary /export/home/sdc/.cache/bazel/_bazel_sdc/install/4934d058a217b4818dc15e0efc1712e0/_embedded_binaries/embedded_tools/jdk/bin/java in /export/home1/sdc_bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/Z800-DEP-JOB1/tensorflow/build/deps

Additional information:
Bazel 0.19.1 installed using:

- wget https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.19.1/bazel-0.19.1-installer-linux-x86_64.sh
- ./bazel-0.19.1-installer-linux-x86_64.sh --prefix=pwd

OS:

```
lsb_release -a
LSB Version: :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: HELiOS
Description: HELiOS release 6.10SP2 (Carbon)
Release: 6.10SP2
Codename: Carbon


java version "1.8.0_152"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b16, mixed mode)
```

See also same post on https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/11557

Comment: Did you try  `bazel clean --expunge`?

Answer (score 1):

Copying my answer from the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/11557), which can hopefully shine light on how this can be debugged:

Bazel works on a self-extracting client-server model, where the client is a C++ binary that extracts the Java server (A-server.jar) and launches it, and communicates with it over RPC. It looks like the client did execute successfully, but it's running into problems communicating with the server. Check if the Java process is running, and do a thread dump to see where it's stuck?

Also consider trying this with a later Bazel version to see if the problem has been fixed in the mean time.